# No more entry for 'Google Chrome' in my 'Browse with...' VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In my VS2012 I don't have anymore entry for Google Chrome in my toolbar for "Browse with..." feature. I notice it yesterday and I know it was working nicely in the past. I have the same problem on my second Win8 computer.

[image]

On my Win7 with VS2012 on it, I have no problem: the 'Google Chrome' entry is present and is working.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click `Browse With...` and add Chrome. Is it possible Chrome was installed after VS? I believe the list is initially populated on installation. I suppose it's possible that a Chrome update changed the location of the Chrome executable or something similar but I'm just guessing there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The Chrome path is as follow: `C:\Users\Thierry\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` as you can see this is local for the user Thierry (myself). Is it not a problem? I mean, this is not something like 'C:\Program Files\...'

Comment: Your visual studio configuration should be per-user as well so I'd say not in this case - but I agree, I don't like Chrome installing itself there